# How to restart a Screen which was called before and remove the previous screen from back stack in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React native project, I have three screens which I have set in navigation set up. In **HomeScreen** I have a customize navigation Toolbar like the below image-

[image]

Here's the code I have written -

```
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerRight: (
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
             <Image style={{width:20, height:20, margin:5, justifyContent:'center'}} source={require('../assets/search.png')} />
             <Image style={{width:20, height:20, margin:5, justifyContent:'center'}} source={require('../assets/cart.png')} />
             <Image style={{width:20, height:20, margin:5, justifyContent:'center'}} source={require('../assets/user.png')} />
        </View>
      ),

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },

});
```

And for two external Screens I have the following **createStackNavigator** set up like below-

```
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: Drawer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  BookDetails: {
    screen: BookDetails,
  },

  CartPage: {
    screen: CartPage,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Cart Page' },
  },

},

);
```

So, **BookDetails** and **cartPage** are two different screen. From **HomeScreen** to go to the **BookDetails** screen, then from **BookDetails** Screen I go to **CartPage** Screen.

After that, in my **CartPage** by a button click I call the **HomeScreen** back again writing the following code-

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
```

Then, myHomeScreen look like this-

[image]

**So, the problem is---**

I don't want my **HomeScreen** toolbar to look like that as I don't want to go back anywhere from this page. I want the **HomeScreen** look like the First image which was like when the app started for the first time.

I am not getting any solution to solve it. So, it would be very nice if someone help out with this code to find out the problem and solve so that I can have my **HomeScreen** like the way I want.

Comment: You can try `popToTop()`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#poptotop

Comment: Can you help me out with the current configuration of my code?

Comment: instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');` , do `this.props.navigation.popToTop()`; it should work :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. It would be very nice if you suggest also - how can I move other screen in the stack rather than only the top.

Comment: You can add keys to your navigation pages and get it's position in the stack then navigate to it; I don't have a working example, but this is the best solution of doing it;